# variable length generic types

Tags: java, generics

i want to do something like this, anyone done something similar?
I have one solution map that has two keys, i am using it for geolocation, but i would like to make it with n number of keys instead.

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Set;

public interface NKeyMap<K..., V> {
    public void clear();
    public boolean containsKey(K...);
    public boolean containsValue(V value);
    public V get(K...);
    public boolean isEmpty();
    public V put(K..., V value);
    public V removeK..., V value);
    public int size();
    public Collection<V> values();
    public Set<K...> keys();
}
```

Comment: Go ahead,What the issue ??

Comment: What is the problem you got?

Comment: Not possible like you posted. What's you intention anyways? [edit] Read your edit; you might want to create ``Tupel<A,B>``, ``Tripel<A,B,C>`` etc. for keys (maybe have a look at javatuples which provide exactly this).

Comment: The problem is that it does not work ;)
I added some comments to my original post

Comment: [c++ just added](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/EhvU7k9E/) variadic templates, perhaps you can switch :)

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. What task are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I think it makes sense, i want to have a map of n number of keys. A map will take one key and one value. I have one solution where i have two keys and one value, this works for geolocation. Now i would like to use n number of keys. Mainly to make the two key solutions easier and i would like to support a more 3D geolocation

Comment: Why dont you do multimensional maps like the last part of my answer

Comment: Oh, I hit this a few years ago... In the end the most practical way was to use an upper bound for all the keys and downcast when necessary, or the code would become unreadable :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not do var-arg generic but you can do something like below

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Set;

public interface NKeyMap<K, V> {
    public void clear();
    public boolean containsKey(K... k );
    public boolean containsValue(V value);
    public V get(K... k);
    public boolean isEmpty();
    public V put(V value, K...k);
    public V remove(V value, K... k);
    public int size();
    public Collection<V> values();
    public Set<K> keys();
}
```

Comment: That is you can't write like interface NKeyMap<K..., V>, you need to write like interface NKeyMap<K, V>

Comment: This wont work since either since i need K to be arbitrary type, K... could be Long, String, Class<T> etc at the same time. In the Scenario where i had two defined keys i could set one to Long and one to String.

Comment: No the ... in the methods will work, the problem was with the interface. Problem remaining is to make it so that K can be if different types

Comment: @Karthik The other are okay they won't produce compilation error as they are on method.

Comment: added code to my github so anyone can see what i did
https://github.com/JohnnyBekkestad/multikeydemo
The only thing remaining is to see if i can get the keys to be different types

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this [post](http://rickyclarkson.blogspot.sg/2008/06/cross-language-generics-trick-java.html) The person tries to simulate this by chaining `pair`

He does this

```
Pair<String, Integer> pair = Pairs.pair("hello", 5);
Pair<Double, Pair<String, Integer>> withDouble = Pairs.pair(3.0, pair);
```

And proposes the below to make it cleaner

```
public class Pair<T, U> { ...
  public <V> Pair<V, Pair<T, U>> prepend(V v) {
   return pair(v, this); } }
```

So that it becomes

```
Pair<Double, Pair<String, Integer>> pair = Pairs.pair("hello", 5).prepend(3.0);
```

Note: you might need to write `Pair`.

Note: Seems he actually endorses javatuples at the end..

**More relevant:**

After reading your comment, this more obvious solution presents itself.
Multidimensional maps, much like multimensional arrays

```
Map<XKey, Map<YKey, Value> >
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need variable-length keys, you can use [javatuples](http://www.javatuples.org) or something similar, which wrap an arbitrary number and arbitrary types of arguments (they provide tuples until a length of 10):

`Map<Triplet<Double,Float,Integer>, Object> mapWithCombinedKeys = ...`

Comment: I will have a look at it